# Angular 8 - ngx-DataTable doesn't show datas

Tags: angular, database, typescript, ngx-datatable

I have a datable that is returning the data from my API, but it is not being rendered. Below is the code:

Module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ModuloEscolaRoutingModule } from './modulo-escola-routing.module';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { MacroareasComponent } from './macroareas/macroareas.component';
import { ProfessoresComponent } from './professores/professores.component';
import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module';
import { NgxDatatableModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        DashboardComponent,
        MacroareasComponent,
        ProfessoresComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        SharedModule,
        ModuloEscolaRoutingModule,
        NgxDatatableModule,
    ]
})
export class ModuloEscolaModule { }
```

My Component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from 'src/app/shared/services/http.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-macroareas',
    templateUrl: './macroareas.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./macroareas.component.scss']
})
export class MacroareasComponent implements OnInit {

    title = 'Macroáreas';
    public macroarea = [];
    loadingIndicator: boolean = true;
    reorderable: boolean = true;
    public right_side_bar: boolean;
    columns = [
      { prop: 'Macroárea' },
      { name: 'Cadastrado em' },
      { name: 'Ação' }
    ];

    constructor(private http: HttpService) {
        this.http.get('macroareas').subscribe(
            (res: any) => {
                this.macroarea = res;
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        )
    }


    ngOnInit() {

    }

    toggleSearch() {
        this.right_side_bar = !this.right_side_bar;
        console.log(this.right_side_bar)
    }

    dismissSearch(event) {
        this.right_side_bar = false;
    }


}
```

And my component.html

```js
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <button (click)="toggleSearch()">filter</button>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5>{{ title }}</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body custom-datatable">
                    <ngx-datatable class="bootstrap" [rows]="macroarea" [loadingIndicator]="loadingIndicator"
                        [columns]="columns" [columnMode]="'force'" [headerHeight]="40" [summaryRow]="true"
                        [summaryPosition]="'bottom'" [footerHeight]="40" [rowHeight]="'auto'"
                        [reorderable]="reorderable" [limit]="10">
                    </ngx-datatable>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the image below I show the data return and how it is displayed on my screen

[image]

the exact amount of rows is being displayed, but the rows are empty and do not show the data.
Would anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: try chaging the location of when you retrieve your data to the `ngOnInit` function.

Comment: It had the same result..nothing changed

Comment: the property name in the data array needs to have the same prop name as the column otherwise wont print anything.

Comment: @BetiniO.Heleno let me know if it worked to insert a proper answer

Comment: worked man.....